# Django & Postgres - percentile (median) and group by

Tags: python, django, postgresql, statistics, subquery

I need to calculate **period medians per seller ID** (see simplyfied model below). The problem is I am unable to construct the ORM query.

Model

```
class MyModel:
    period = models.IntegerField(null=True, default=None)
    seller_ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), default=list)
    aux = JSONField(default=dict)
```

Query

```
queryset = (
    MyModel.objects.filter(period=25)
    .annotate(seller_id=Func(F("seller_ids"), function="unnest"))
    .values("seller_id")
    .annotate(
        duration=Cast(KeyTextTransform("duration", "aux"), IntegerField()),
        median=Func(
            F("duration"),
            function="percentile_cont",
            template="%(function)s(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %(expressions)s)",
        ),
    )
    .values("median", "seller_id")
)
```

[ArrayField aggregation (`seller_id`) source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32748136/4183498)

I think what I need to do is something along the lines below

```
select t.*, p_25, p_75
from t join
     (select district,
             percentile_cont(0.25) within group (order by sales) as p_25,
             percentile_cont(0.75) within group (order by sales) as p_75
      from t
      group by district
     ) td
     on t.district = td.district
```

[above example source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39683360/4183498)

Python 3.7.5, Django 2.2.8, Postgres 11.1

Comment: To clarify, are you using django with SQLServer?

Comment: @ivissani there's a `postgresql` tag under the question so no.

Comment: yeah... sorry about that

Comment: What is the error you have?

Comment: So what's your question?  Whats wrong with the query you showed?  Are you trying to do this using the ORM or?

Comment: Added model and example query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a `Median` child class of the `Aggregate` class as was done by Ryan Murphy (https://gist.github.com/rdmurphy/3f73c7b1826cacee34f6c2a855b12e2e). `Median` then works just like `Avg`:

```
    from django.db.models import Aggregate, FloatField


    class Median(Aggregate):
        function = 'PERCENTILE_CONT'
        name = 'median'
        output_field = FloatField()
        template = '%(function)s(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %(expressions)s)'
```

Then to find the median of a field use

```
    my_model_aggregate = MyModel.objects.all().aggregate(Median('period'))
```

which is then available as `my_model_aggregate['period__median']`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what did the trick.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func, IntegerField
from django.db.models.aggregates import Aggregate


queryset = (
    MyModel.objects.filter(period=25)
    .annotate(duration=Cast(KeyTextTransform("duration", "aux"), IntegerField()))
    .filter(duration__isnull=False)
    .annotate(seller_id=Func(F("seller_ids"), function="unnest"))
    .values("seller_id")  # group by
    .annotate(
        median=Aggregate(
            F("duration"),
            function="percentile_cont",
            template="%(function)s(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY %(expressions)s)",
        ),
    )
)
```

Notice the [`median` annotation employs `Aggregate`](https://django-postgres-stats.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/postgres_stats/aggregates.html) and not `Func` as in the question.
Also, [order of annotate() and filter() clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) as well as [order of annotate() and values() clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) **matters a lot**!

BTW the resulting SQL is without a nested select and join.