# Filling in missing values with a median in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, median

How can I replace avg with a median calculation in this?

```sql
select *
, coalesce(val, avg(val) over (order by t rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding)) as fixed
from (
    values
    (1, 10),
    (2, NULL),
    (3, 10),
    (4, 15),
    (5, 11),
    (6, NULL),
    (7, NULL),
    (8, NULL),
    (9, NULL)
) as test(t, val)
;
```

Is there a legal version of this?

```sql
percentile_cont(0.5) within group(order by val) over (order by t rows between 3 preceding and 1 preceding)
```

Comment: This is the closest answer I can find but it's not the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39683330/percentile-calculation-with-a-window-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `percentile_cont()` is an aggregate function, for which there is no equivalent window function.

One workaround is to use an inline subquery to do the aggregate computation.

If `id`s are always increasing, then you can do:

```
select 
    t.*,
    coalesce(
        t.val, 
        (
            select percentile_cont(0.5) within group(order by t1.val)
            from test t1
            where t1.id between t.id - 3 and t.id - 1
        )
    ) fixed
from test t
```

Otherwise, you need an additional level of nesting:

```
select 
    t.*,
    coalesce(
        t.val, 
        (
            select percentile_cont(0.5) within group(order by t1.val)
            from (select val from test t1 where t1.id < t.id order by t1.id desc limit 3) t1
        )
    ) fixed
from test t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=dcea609bb93c159cb53c265ce54c85a5)** - both queries yield:

```
id |  val | fixed
-: | ---: | :----
 1 |   10 | 10   
 2 | null | 10   
 3 |   10 | 10   
 4 |   15 | 15   
 5 |   11 | 11   
 6 | null | 11   
 7 | null | 13   
 8 | null | 11   
 9 | null | null
```

Comment: That looks good. Do you expect there's an efficiency difference between a subquery and a home-baked windowing function? The sub-query is clearly best if missing data is rare.